# Unable to get mp4 tkhd info using go-mp4

Tags: go, parsing, video, mp4

Using package `github.com/abema/go-mp4` when i try to run the example in the docs i get following error:

```
invalid operation: box (variable of type *mp4.BoxInfo) is not an interface
```

Here is the example that i am trying:

```
// extract specific boxes
boxes, err := mp4.ExtractBox(file, nil, mp4.BoxPath{mp4.BoxTypeMoov(), mp4.BoxTypeTrak(), mp4.BoxTypeTkhd()})
if err != nil {
   :
}
for _, box := range boxes {
  tkhd := box.(*mp4.Tkhd)
  fmt.Println("track ID:", tkhd.TrackID)
}
```

https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/abema/go-mp4#section-readme

Comment: You should ask for support on github! I think there's something wrong here, maybe it hasn't been updated after some modifications.

Comment: The code does a type assertion on a variable `box` that is not an Interface, I can't know what your intention is, but if you declare `box` as an interface before you do the range, it might do the trick for you. [ref](https://go.dev/tour/methods/15)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it is an error of my sample code.

I created Pull Request to fix it.
https://github.com/abema/go-mp4/pull/113/files

When you find any other problems about go-mp4, I would be grateful if you could create new Issue on GitHub.
https://github.com/abema/go-mp4/issues